# Something like “mvn undeploy” to remove artifacts from Nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

After a `mvn deploy` (to a local Nexus) on a project with more than 50 modules I realized that the deployed artifacts had all wrong file names (suffix zip instead of war etc).

Is there something like `mvn undeploy` to remove these from Nexus again?

Comment: I think you can only do this through the Nexus admin counsel.  You can't do it with maven.

Comment: There is no chance to delete something from nexus without logging in as nexus administrator. You can't do it through Maven.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can delete it by using Curl command :

http://host:port/nexus/service/local/repositories/repo-id/content/group-id/artifact-id/version

The delete request can be sent with these parameters, I like to suppress the output except HTTP status code, so that it’s easier to check the result of a series of such commands run from shell script.

```
curl –request DELETE –write “%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n” –user admin:admin123 –output /dev/null –silent url
```

For example you can execute this script from a Freestyle jenkins job.

Comment: In its simplest form: `curl -X DELETE -u admin:admin123  "http://somedomain/nexus/content/repositories/myrepo/com/test/test-artifact/1.0.0/"`